# Is there a way of plotting ParametricListPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, polyhedra

I wish to draw a closed shape in 3D using a list of points. Specifically, I want to plot the product of an expensive function "qfun" of angular coordinate theta, with a simple function of angular coordinate phi. For example:

```
qfun[theta_] = Cos[5 theta] Sin[theta]^2
ParametricPlot3D[
 (1+0.2 qfun[theta] Cos[2 phi]) {Cos[phi] Sin[theta],Sin[phi] Sin[theta], Cos[theta]}
 , {theta, 0, Pi}
 , {phi, -Pi, Pi}]
```

will plot the shape r[theta,phi]=(1+0.2 qfun[theta]*Cos[2 phi]). However, in my case qfun is a very complicated mess (so I won't post the specific form). I can calculate qfun in a useful time only at rational values of theta. It would be easy to create a grid of values for the skeleton of a parametric plot, or to smoothly join a series of ellipses at different values of theta. (I wish this were a figure of rotation!) Could it be treated as a polyhedron, and smoothed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a table of values, then interpolate, then plot the interpolated function like in your example.

```
qfun[theta_Rationnal] = Cos[5 theta] Sin[theta]^2

table00 = Table[
     {{theta, phi}
      , (1+2/10 qfun[theta] Cos[2 phi]) {Cos[phi] Sin[theta],Sin[phi] Sin[theta], Cos[theta]}
      }
, {theta, -Pi (* Not 0 ! *), Pi, Pi/10}
, {phi, -Pi, Pi , 
      Pi/10}] // N // Flatten[#, 1] &;

fInterpol = 
 Interpolation[table00, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
  PeriodicInterpolation -> True]

ParametricPlot3D[
 fInterpol[theta, phi], {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image]